# Unable to install sentence-transformers, getting error

Tags: python, nlp

Running below command after installing python 3.10.

pip3 install -U sentence-transformers

1. List item

ERROR: Cannot install sentence-transformers==0.1.0, sentence-transformers==0.2.0, sentence-transformers==0.2.1, sentence-transformers==0.2.2, sentence-transformers==0.2.3, sentence-transformers==0.2.4, sentence-transformers==0.2.4.1, sentence-transformers==0.2.5, sentence-transformers==0.2.5.1, sentence-transformers==0.2.6.1, sentence-transformers==0.2.6.2, sentence-transformers==0.3.0, sentence-transformers==0.3.1, sentence-transformers==0.3.2, sentence-transformers==0.3.3, sentence-transformers==0.3.4, sentence-transformers==0.3.5, sentence-transformers==0.3.5.1, sentence-transformers==0.3.6, sentence-transformers==0.3.7, sentence-transformers==0.3.7.1, sentence-transformers==0.3.7.2, sentence-transformers==0.3.8, sentence-transformers==0.3.9, sentence-transformers==0.4.0, sentence-transformers==0.4.1, sentence-transformers==0.4.1.1, sentence-transformers==0.4.1.2, sentence-transformers==1.0.0, sentence-transformers==1.0.1, sentence-transformers==1.0.2, sentence-transformers==1.0.3, sentence-transformers==1.0.4, sentence-transformers==1.1.0, sentence-transformers==1.1.1, sentence-transformers==1.2.0, sentence-transformers==1.2.1, sentence-transformers==2.0.0 and sentence-transformers==2.1.0 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
sentence-transformers 2.1.0 depends on torch>=1.6.0
...............

To fix this you could try to:

1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict

ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#fixing-conflicting-dependencies
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.2.4; however, version 22.0.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3.10 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error, here is how I fixed it:

- first install torch 1.10.0 using the following

```sh
conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=11.3 -c pytorch
```

- then install sentence-transformers 2.1.0 by

```sh
pip install -U sentence-transformers
```